# Ionic 2 Align Button Label to left

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I created a button in Ionic 2 as follows:

```
  <button secondary block round padding style="text-align : left;">
    <ion-icon ios="ios-key" md="md-key"></ion-icon>
    Login
  </button>
```

I am trying to align the button text to left side but its not coming there. Is there build in twik available to achieve that?

Comment: When you say align do you mean completely align the text to the left next to the edge of the button or just swap the icon and text position over so the text is central on the left and the icon is central on the right?

Comment: @Will.Harris When I say align I meant to completely align the text to the left next to the edge of the button .

Comment: And where should the icon be e.g. remain in the center / pushed out to the right / just to the side of where the text ends?

Comment: I want Icon at the left side and just after that the text

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ionic wraps the contents of the button into a `<span>` tag which has the class `.button-inner`. So the HTML markup looks something like this when you inspect it

```
<button secondary block round padding>
    <span class="button-inner">            
        <ion-icon ios="ios-key" md="md-key" item-right></ion-icon>
        Login
    </span>    
    <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
</button>
```

The `.button-inner` class applies flexbox properties to position the text and icons central. You can overwrite the [`justify-content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/) property and change the value from `center` to `flex-start` and this will tell the content (the text and icon) to start from the beginning of the box.

**Example**

If you want to apply it to all buttons

```
.button-inner{
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

If you want to apply it to a specific button (where `.specific-button` is added as a class to a button component)

```
.specific-button .button-inner{
     justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Exactly the thing I was looking for.

Comment: I had this working as described in the answer in Ionic 3, but now it no longer seems to work in Ionic 4.

Comment: @S.Baggy did you ever figure it out? I found this https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-4-tutorial-mastering-web-components-in-ionic-4 does it means only way to achieve it is to make a new button component?

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego sorry I do not recall now. I have moved off the mobile apps the past half a year.

Comment: @S.Baggy, at least I'll be moving away from Ionic for the next release of my app

Answer (score 0):

Because Ionic use its class generate default css. So you should use SASS to customize CSS .

For example :

```
<button class="item">
    <ion-icon ios="ios-key" md="md-key"></ion-icon>
     Login
  </button>
```

file styles.scss

```
.item{
   @extend secondary;
   @extend block;
   text-align : left;
}
```

Comment: I think you should read this topic : http://www.joshmorony.com/a-guide-to-styling-an-ionic-2-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `item-left` attribute inside the `button`-tag. No need for `class=""` or `style=""`.

```
<button secondary block round padding item-left>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-key" md="md-key"></ion-icon>
    Login
</button>
```

More information [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#buttons-in-components)